# Xpages - How to save values to list box that have been entered by client side javascript

Tags: xpages

I have a list box that I am adding and removing items with client side javascript.  The issue is that these new values are not being saved to the list box(binded to field).  The only value that comes back is the original one that was set in list box.  The values are all there on the client since I can loop through the array.  How can I get these values to replace the value that is currently there?

Comment: After changing the values with clientside. Do you save the document with a simple action or do you post them another way or?

Comment: I save the document using a simple action (Save Document).

Comment: maybe the notes field is not multivalue with correct separator?

Comment: Appears I can added to an edit box just fine. Not sure why the values are not being retained upon submit.

Comment: Maybe you try to retrieve only the first value. You should provide sample code

Answer (score 0):

By default the listbox have a validator that you may not see during save, (you need to add error controls to see it)  and the validator do not accept new values added using CSJS

If you set disableValidators="true" in the listbox control you suppress the validator and the save works fine. you also need to select the entries in the listbox using CSJS before you save,

Credits goes to Jesse Gallagher

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In the `List Box properties`, you must to set `mutiple = true`